# Expectation when conditioning on a function of a r.v.

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, conditional-expectation

I have seen the equality $E[Y \mid f(W)] = E[Y \mid W]$ being used in many econometric derivations. For example, in demonstrating the control function approach for identification ([here is the Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Control_function_(econometrics))) $E[U \mid X,V] = E[U \mid \pi(Z) + V, V] = E[U \mid \ Z, V]$.

If generally $\sigma(f(W)) \subseteq \sigma(W)$, how can $E[Y \mid \sigma(f(W))] = E[Y \mid \sigma(W)]$ hold?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $f \equiv 0$ then $E(Y|f(W))=EY$ so the equality does not hold always. It holds if $\sigma (f(W))=\sigma (W)$ which is true if $f$ is bijective and $f^{-1}$ is also Borel measurable